# Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: type "enum_*" already exists

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I was attempting to perform a `sequelize` db migration to my test database with the following user model, for the reference there had been a previous migration as well.

```
const User = Sequelize.define('user', {
    user_id: {
        type: sequelize.STRING,
        primary_key: true,
    },
    firstName:{
        type: sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    lastName:{
        type: sequelize.STRING
    },
    dob:{
        type: sequelize.DATE
    },
    birth_time:{
        type: sequelize.TIME,
        allowNull: true
    },
    gender:{
        type: sequelize.ENUM,
        values: ['male', 'female']
    }
});
```

But while doing so I am receiving the following error once a few db queries are executed.

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: type "enum_yyy" already exists
    at Query.formatError (/home/caesar/Workspace/Devmetry/Projects/xxx/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:366:16)
    at /home/caesar/Workspace/Devmetry/Projects/xxx/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:72:18
    at tryCatcher (/home/caesar/Workspace/Devmetry/Projects/xxx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/caesar/Workspace/xxx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/caesar/Workspace/Devmetry/Projects/xxx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/caesar/Workspace/Devmetry/Projects/xxx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/caesar/Workspace/Devmetry/Projects/xxx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:689:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/home/caesar/Workspace/Devmetry/Projects/xxx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/caesar/Workspace/Devmetry/Projects/xxx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/caesar/Workspace/Devmetry/Projects/xxx/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:137:15)
```

The `db.sync` method that I have utilized is as follows.

```
Sequelize.sync({ alter: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Database & tables generated!`)
});
```

Anyone having suggestions on fixing this issue, without a hard complete db migration.

Comment: There are an open issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2554. Check too the following related issues: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2577 and https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7649

Answer (score 8):

It seems an issue with postgres. However you can use this technique. It works.

```
    gender: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 'male',
        validate: {
            customValidator: (value) => {
                const enums = ['male', 'female']
                if (!enums.includes(value)) {
                    throw new Error('not a valid option')
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Bheemaraju's answer, that code snippet he shared, implies validating your Enums with JavaScript, so that in the Database the data will be stored as plain strings. Yet each time you try to insert a value, it will validate the value you are inserting through validator function and throw an error if it does not match any of the enums values.

> ```
> gender: {
>         type: DataTypes.STRING, // Store values as plain strings
>         allowNull: false,
>         defaultValue: 'male',
>         validate: {
>             customValidator: (value) => {
>                 const enums = ['male', 'female'] // These are your enum values
>                 if (!enums.includes(value)) { // Use Array.includes() to validate.
>                     throw new Error('not a valid option')
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     },
> ```